# java.lang.NullPointerException in textview inside asyncTask

Tags: android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, progressdialog, textview, android

If I use the following code, I will have no error, but there will be a freeze time.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    setContentView(R.layout.profilepic);
    initialize();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    email = bundle.getString("Email");
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    String response = null;
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emaillog", email));              

    try {
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://whatstherex.info/checkU.php", postParameters);
        res = response.toString();
        res = res.replaceAll("null", "");                   
        username = res.toString();
        tvProfilePic.setText("Hi " + username + ", you are encourage to add a profile picture.");

    }catch(Exception e){
        res = e.toString();
        tvProfilePic.setText(res);
    }
}
```

But if I use this code with asyncTask and progressDialog like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
    setContentView(R.layout.profilepic);
    initialize();
    getUsername();
}

private AsyncTask<String, Void, String> task;

public void getUsername(){      
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    email = bundle.getString("Email");
    task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {

        ProgressDialog dialog;
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
        String response = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("emaillog", email));
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Profilepic.this, ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading Data...");       
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //
            try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://whatstherex.info/checkU.php", postParameters);
                res = response.toString();
                res = res.replaceAll("null", "");   
                username = res.toString();
                return username;
            }catch(Exception e){
                res = e.toString();
                return res;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
            if(result.length()< 25){
                username = result;
                tvProfilePic.setText("Hi " + result + ", you are encourage to add a profile picture.");
                dialog.dismiss();
            }else{
                tvProfilePic.setText(result);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
    task.execute(); 
}
```

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` in the textview.

What's the problem? Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue with `NullPointerException` appearing?

Comment: I don't see anything about a textview, show the code and logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use tvProfilePic but I don't see where you define it.

In case you are not defining it, it should be done in a similar way as

`tvProfilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)`

Are you doing this?
Note that 'profile_pic' is the name in the layout XML document.

Answer (score 0):

You are using tvProfilePic as a textview but i can't see where you defined it.
if you are not defining it then define it using something like 
tvProfilePic = findViewById(R.id.profile_pic)

You are getting nullpointerexception because your tvProfilePic is null